# How to interrupt a thread submitted to newSingleThreadExecutor in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

Given that I have the following test-code:

```
import java.util.concurrent._

object TestTime {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("starting....")
    val service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor
    val r = new Callable[Unit]() {
      override def call(): Unit = {
        //your task
        val t0 = System.nanoTime
        val total = sum(1000000000)
        val t1 = System.nanoTime
        println("Elapsed time " + (t1 - t0) / 1e9 + " secs")
        println(s"total = $total")
      }
    }
    val f = service.submit(r)
    try {
      // attempt the task for 2 second
      f.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    } catch {
      case _: TimeoutException =>
        f.cancel(true)
        println(s"Timeout....")
    } finally {
      service.shutdown()
    }
    println("after 2 seconds....")
    for(i <- 1 to 2){
      println(s"$i ...")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    println("main thread ends...")
  }

 //Given that sum() is written by others and I cannot change it.
 def sum(k: Int): BigInt = {
    var total: BigInt = 0
    for (i <- 1 to k) {
      total += i
    }
    total
  }
}
```

I would like to execute the `sum` at most 2 seconds.  If it exceeds the time limit, the corresponding thread should be interrupted immediately. To interrupt that thread, I have tried two methods when catch `TimeoutException`:

> `f.cancel(true)`
>
> `service.shutdownNow()`

However, according to my test, the above methods cannot interrupt the thread.

So I would like to know is there method to interrupt a thread compulsively.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to JavaDocs for both [`Future#cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) and [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--), the typical implementation is that these methods result in interrupting the underlying thread.

> If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Note particuarly the last comment.  Thread interruption via the [`Thread#interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) method is a cooperative process.  When one thread interrupts another, it results in setting the target thread's interrupted status.  Also, if the target thread is blocked in certain specific methods, then that thread will experience an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

If the code executing in the target thread neither checks for interrupted status periodically via the [`Thread#isInterrupted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--) method nor calls a blocking method and handles `InterruptedException`, then interruption effectively does nothing.  That code is not cooperating in the interruption process, so there is effectively no way to shut it down, despite thread interruption.

```
//Given that sum() is written by others and I cannot change it.
```

Ideally, long-running code intended for execution in background threads would be changed to cooperate in the thread interruption.  In your example, a viable technique would be to change `sum` to check `Thread#isInterrupted` every N iterations of the `for` loop, and if interrupted, abort the loop.  Then, it could either throw an exception to indicate that it didn't complete or possibly return some sentinel `BigInt` value to indicate the abort if that's appropriate.

If the invoked code truly cannot be changed, then you cannot halt it by thread interruption.  You could potentially use [daemon threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-) so that at least these threads won't block JVM exit during shutdown.